How can I dismiss the49.maui.BottomSheet within the ViewModel?
So I've done some searching, attempted to ask ChatGPT, and tried several different methods, but I cannot, for the life of me, get the bottom sheet to dismiss.
I have a Page called CategoryItemPage which has its own ViewModel called CategoryItemViewModel, which is passed to the code-behind via DI. Additionally, I'm requesting a transient instance of ItemBottomSheet. ItemBottomSheet extends BottomSheet and requests its own ViewModel be injected. ItemBottomSheet and has several entries and a Save button.
Now, there's a command in CategoryItemViewModel which displays the ItemBottomSheet using bottomSheet.ShowAsync();
The Save button in the bottom sheet has a binding to its own ViewModel, and I'm doing this:
<the49:BottomSheet xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:the49="https://schemas.the49.com/dotnet/2023/maui"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"       
             x:Class="MyApp.Controls.ItemBottomSheet"
             HasHandle="True"
             x:Name="ItemSheet">

...

<Button Text="{Binding ButtonText}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" Command="{Binding OnSaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference ItemSheet}}"/>

In the ItemBottomSheetViewModel, I have the following:
public ICommand OnSaveCommand { get; set; }

...

OnSaveCommand = new Command<ItemBottomSheet>(OnSave); // This is set in the constructor

...

private async void OnSave(ItemBottomSheet bs)
{
  // Validation
  await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
  bs.DismissAsync(false);
}

The bottom sheet just refuses to dismiss and I cannot see why. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong please?
Additionally I've tried:
Setting the ItemBottomSheet up as a service and injecting it into the CategoryItemViewModel AND the ItemBottomSheetViewModel - but this creates a circular dependancy.
Storing the ItemBottomSheetViewModel in the code behind, and pointing the XAML Clicked to a method in the code behind which calls save on the view model and tries to dismiss itself, but that didn't work either.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions on this!

I was having the same issues and my bug was that I forgot to include .UseBottomSheet() in my MauiProgram.cs. Everything was working except for the DismissAsync would hang indefinitely. Once I added this call, programmatically calling DismissAsync started working.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The method DismissAsync still hangs, I don't think that UseBottomSheet did anything...
